# How to find file size greater than 200 MB in unix from a directory and its sub directory

Tags: unix

Even though I used this command I am still getting output lesser than the 200 MB as well.

Command used:

```
find . -type f -size +200M -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

Output example

```
-rw-r--r--   1 dummy  dummy     101K Jul 27 22:43 ./sub_dir1/sub_dir2_1/file_1
-rw-r--r--   1 dummy  dummy     158M Jul 27 22:44 ./sub_dir1/sub_dir2_1/file_2
-rw-r--r--   1 dummy  dummy     1.1G Jul 27 22:44 ./sub_dir1/sub_dir2_2/file_3
-rw-r--r--   1 dummy  dummy      11M Jul 27 22:45 ./sub_dir1/sub_dir2_2/file_4
```

Comment: try `find . -type f  -size +200M  -printf "%f  %s\n"`

Comment: Printf is getting error out with  below                                                                                      find: bad option -printf
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list

Comment: You are using `"` in command right ? Please share what command you have executed

Comment: Yes i have used the command as it is in terminal ,may be its a version issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.
In some of the unix versions, We can't directly use the size as it is for the find commands.

In this it occupying 512 bytes.

Hence (200000000/512) = 390625

Unix command perfected:

```
find . -type f -size +390625 -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

Now it is working as expected.